# Does China have the most aggressive moon exploration plan as of 2013?

Tags: the-moon, lunar-landing

[China is launching a rover](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-23870765) to the moon this year, with more launches and returning samples coming soon. They also plan to have humans on the moon within the next decade.

The Moon offers many benefits for exploration beyond Earth -

- Abundant resources
- A stable launch platform with a much lower gravity well, and
- Easy access to shielding from the hazards of open space (i.e. radiation & impacts)

Identifying the best locations to

- Harvest resources
- Set up factories, and
- Create habitats

would all seem to be basic logistical, political and economic necessities for exploration of the Moon and the Solar system.

Does China have the most aggressive moon exploration plan as of 2013?

Comment: By what measure?

Comment: Apparently by the measure of the first soft landing since 1976.

Comment: No. It's moving damn fast but it's starting from a distant position and it's quite a while yet before it catches up with the leaders. The program is very aggressive but less advanced than what others have already achieved.

Comment: As both the native Americans and Vikings will attest, first has little to offer over persistence.

Comment: @JamesJenkins a race has a predetermined end point, i.e the moon. The vikings weren't really in a race they were just pillaging. Comparing apples and oranges. This is why it's important that we have predetermined metrics to work by, if none are given in the Question its customary to ask. Erik assumed the first past the post method, gerrit chose to ask you for the metric. Therefore if you say persistence is your metric, not being there first, then what is your definition and how would you measure if a country is 'winning' the race?

Comment: @JamesJenkins It seems what you mean by "agressive" is on track to dominate colonization of the moon. Am I reading you right? If so, I suggest explicitly mentioning colonization as your metric (in your question wording).

Comment: @called2voyage I would not say 'dominate' but on track to fully explore & make use of the resources.  I believe China is planning on a robot base in the near future, not strickly colinization.  In theory you could have all your mining and consruction done by bots, and just have poeple go to the Moon to take a brand new ship to Titan.

Comment: @JamesJenkins If not dominate, then what? Are you asking if they'll be the first to do that? How do we determine "most agressive"?

Comment: Perhaps the Chinese just haven't realized that the moon isn't the best place to go first -- or that state-run space programs aren't nearly as robust as private enterprise.

Comment: I think we now have the answer to this 5-year old question!

Comment: I've voted to re-open. @JamesJenkins what do you think? Perhaps a slight wording change?  *Did it turn out after all that China had...* ;-) Seriously though I don't think this should have been closed. By any reasonable definition China had the most aggressive plan in 2013, it's pretty obvious now.

Comment: @uhoh I think it is good to re-open,  You are a lot more active here currently then I am, feel free to edit if you think it is appropriate.

Comment: I don’t think they’re the most aggressive - the most pragmatic might be a better choice of words. That, and they don’t have a political system that’s jerking them around every four to eight years. The US needn’t either, but them’s the breaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, American [LADEE is scheduled for the next week](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Atmosphere_and_Dust_Environment_Explorer), but that doesn't count -- it doen't land, right?

The current Roscosmos plans are with [Luna-Glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna-Glob) scheduled for [the second half of 2016](http://www.ato.ru/content/lunnye-plany-npo-imeni-s-lavochkina).

Indian [Chandrayaan-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrayaan-2) will not be ready until at least 2015.

Japanese [SELENE-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELENE-2) is not to be expected earlier than 2017.

That leaves Chang'e as the current winner candidate for the first soft landing  on the Moon in 37 years. :-)