# Why did China land a rover on the moon?

Tags: the-moon, rovers, chang-e

Why did China land the Chang’e-4 rover on the moon? What was it supposed to accomplish or explore?

Comment: Well, I think your question could have also a good political answer on the https://politics.stackexchange.com . Here you can get only a space technology answer. *(Reviewers: it is NOT a closure suggestion, the space technology aspect is well-answerable and ontopic)*

Comment: Did you search the internet for your answer before posting?

Comment: Aaron, note that they landed it on the ***far side*** of the moon, which has never been done before.  If you're not aware of that, that was the main novelty.   (An important sub issue is, they're the first with a moon-orbiting-radio-relay satellite, in support of being on the far side.)

Comment: NOtice by the way that this five year old question now seems to be answered!  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1656

Comment: A one hour CGTN show, in English!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vg9GBSHfESk

Comment: no one has answered: "Because it was there…" yet I see *cough-cough*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The mission objectives are:

> The main scientific objective of CE-4 is to provide scientific data
>   for lunar far side research, including: 1) general spatial
>   environmental study of lunar far side；2) general research on the
>   surface, shallow layer and deep layer of lunar far side；3) detection of
>   low frequency radio on lunar far side using Low Frequency Radio
>   Detector, which would be the first time of using such frequency band
>   in lunar exploration history.

Title:      Scientific Objectives of China Chang E 4 CE-4 Lunar Far-side Exploration Mission

Authors:    Zhang, Hongbo; Zeng, Xingguo; Chen, Wangli

[source](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017DPS....4921905Z)

Comment: What about the political objectives?

Comment: @Innovine political objectives of research that's not directly economically beneficial are *always* the same: to show off how country is rich, powerful, advanced and dedicated to do it. Whatever "it" is.

Comment: I understand and fully agree. But as its probably the biggest reason why they are doing it, I think it should be addressed in the answers.

Comment: @Innovine What political objectives could there possibly be? There's nothing special at all about landing a rover on the moon. I doubt any other countries care for any reason other than science.

Answer (score 13):

Why did China land a rover on the moon? (Chang'e-3)

> To get to the other side! (Chang'e 4)

Hover cursor above to reveal answer.

(Hint: analogous to *Why did the chicken cross the road?*)

But seriously folks, here is a one hour English [CGTN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGTN_(TV_channel)) broadcast of the mission, going into great detail on the justification and goals.

Comment: good one, old chap !   :)  that's a classic

Comment: +1 :) thats fun!